# Operating system not found in virtualisation

Tags: debian, virtualization, iso-image

I have download an image for a debian computer. But if I will startup that image with vmWare I get the following message:

[image: Exiting intel PXE ROM. Operating system not found]

Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to net boot?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: no just starting

Comment: Go into the firmware settings and verify the virtual optical disk drive is attempted before the network boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ISO Image is simply a file version of a CD or DVD ROM.  To use this with VMware workstation you need to select to first boot from CD-ROM as it defaults to hard disk and network boot first.

The simplest solution is to follow the Wizard in VMware workstation selecting `Typical` and the using the `Installer disc image (iso)` option to point to the located of the downloaded Debian image:

[image]

Alternatively if the CD-ROM Device is attached and the ISO image mounted (Go to `Virtual Machine Settings`, select `CD/DVD (SATA)` and complete the `Use ISO Image file:` field with the location of your Debian ISO.  Check the `connected` if powered on and also the `Connect at power on` check boxes) then it should boot if no OS is found on the virtual disk.

Another alternative if you are quick, immediately after powering on the VM you can press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get a boot menu - from there you can select to boot from CD.  However, the ISO image has to be connected.

**Note:** where I say CD this can also mean DVD - it is the same process for both ISO format types.